# Estimate memory usage C++ Ubuntu

Tags: c++, gcc, ubuntu-18.04

I have a memory intensive application in which the following structs are created at some point.

```cpp
struct NeighborData {
    int flags;
    int id;
};
struct Node {
    int id;
    std::vector<NeighborData> neighbors;
};
struct Graph {
    std::vector<Node> nodeList;
};
```

During the application execution, the `Graph` data struct is created. I am trying to estimate the amount of memory used by creating a new `Graph` object as below.

`total_memory = sizeof(Node) * nodeList.capacity() + aggregate_over_all_nodes(sizeof(NeighborData) * neighbors.capacity()`

I have around 3E5 nodes and roughly 2E6 edges in the graph. So its a relatively large data set. During application run, at some point, a method `CreateGraph()` gets called. On generating the graph, the memory used by the application appears to increase by almost 150 MB as indicated by the ubuntu system monitor. However, my memory estimates calculated by the method above appear to be much lower and off by more than 100MB. Therefore the two questions below.

- Is my way of estimating memory used by the `Graph` struct correct? Or is there a better way to do this?
- If I am certain, that my process does not allocate any new memory after the `CreateGraph()` call, could there by any other reasons for the ubuntu system monitor to show a higher memory usage than what I estimated?

Comment: Memory management is not free. The C++ library requires some overhead for managing memory. If all your vectors are very small -- seems like the average is two `NeighborData` values per vector -- the relative overhead can be quite large. Can't give a definitive answer without more analysis.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Would it be better to switch to `std::array`? I rechecked. I had my number of nodes wrong (will update the question). I think I have around 300k and average connections per node are 8.

Comment: Making `neighbors` into a `std::array` eliminates all dynamic heap allocation on that level, leaving you with a single vector of Nodes. That's going to be negligible overhead. Just one vector.

Comment: The interesting part is:  using  g++ 9.2.1, declaring Graph g1; ... then   cout << sizeof(g1)  reports 24 bytes, regardless of how many elements, regardless of sizeof elements.  This is the automatic memory used.  The dynamic memory (for most implementations) requires the summation of each Node of g1.  I would apply a function to each g1 element to compute the elements unique byte count, and simply add them together for dynamic memory.

Answer (score 0):

Vectors allocate memory in a linearly amortized fashion. They start with one element, then double the allocation whenever they need more memory.

So, on average, you get to use 1.5 times the needed memory. Or is it sqrt(2) times? Anyway, around 1.5 times.

Then, as mentioned in the comment a vector itself needs space. Probably at least 8 bytes for the length, and 8 bytes for the pointer. If all your vector are small, then this overhead may be significant.

Lastly, you can't trust the system memory report, most of the time. It might also over-allocate memory to reduce allocation overhead.

Comment: He's already compensating for vector overallocation by checking `capacity` instead of `size`